# get rows by value in array in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

i have a question about searching in MySQL.I couldn't find answer for long time.

I use symfony 3.1 and i have the next situation:
I have column `site_languages` (longtext,   (DC2Type:simple_array)  ) in sql with values (for example) "0,1,7", "11,15,27" etc

So my question is:
 how i can select row by `site_languages` which include in array a search value?

I tried use LIKE, checked REGEXP but for example if i need search by value "1" it will return rows with 11/51/111 etc too.I was thinking about keep values like "[1],[15]" But i think there is exist easier and right solution for it?

Comment: Can you change your table design. It is not how you should do things. Never store multiple values in a single column!!!

Comment: juergen d, why not? Symfony gives tools for store array/json and other objects, I understand that i can create new table for every column with multiple values, but i think there is better way exist for work with stored arrays.

Comment: Well if it is such good practice then why are you having problems right now?

Comment: juergen d, problems started when this values from just storing column have turned into "key" columns. There exist something like method `MEMBER OF` , but i don't understand how to use(sql syntax error) and will it help me or not.

Comment: @juergend I would say that your statement is an overgeneralization. There can be cases where having a list of values is what you want. In this case, it looks like 28 columns would be required to deal with all the languages. If there's a method to do as the OP asked, that might be the right solution.

Comment: @ArtemYanin Did you use just `1` as your regex? If you use `(^|,)1(,|$)` it matches a 1 that is preceded by a comma and followed by a comma or it may be preceded by the beginning of the line or end of the line.  I'm not going to comment on whether or not this is good practice to use in SQL, I just like writing regex's.

Comment: @JoeyHarwood: Are you serious? This is a classic many to many relation and this can easily be handled in a DB schema without storing a list. But maybe you know it better than me.

Comment: @JoeyHarwood. YES! this regex query is exactly what i need! Thank you very much! Can you make it as answer on question, so i will make it correct answer?

Comment: @juergend I'm saying that we don't know exactly what he's trying to achieve. In the general sense, as you say you should try to avoid this. Advising him that there is a likely better method of storing the data is good, telling him "Never store multiple values in a single column!!!" is not helpful. In my current job (in Big Query), we just made the decision to have a column that is comma separated lists. We weighed the pros and cons, and came up with this. 'Never' is not a word you should use lightly in my opinion

Comment: Joey Harwood, i just want to store the indexes of the languages selected by users, often its only 1 language, more than one will be maybe 5% of all rows, as for me its really better to keep it as multiple values in column because there is no needed JOIN queries to other tables etc.Symfony converting this column to php array just when u extracted it, so if REGEXP is not "harder" than JOIN i don't see anything bad in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to solve this issue by using a regex you can use this regex `(^|,)1(,|$)` to match a 1 that is preceded by a comma and followed by a comma OR the 1 may be preceded by the beginning of the line or end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider normalizing your DB table but if you insist to keep it this way you can save it as json then retrieve all rows and iterate (bad idea) but is ok if it is a short table

Comment: this way is more longer than keep values with some "triggers" of value's start and end, like i described: [value1],[value2] so you can find it by LIKE '%[your_value]%', so no selecting and iterations on php needed

Comment: Then you should do it correctly, thus, normalize your table by creating new table.